# Time-based Workflow not triggering

Tags: trigger, workflow, field-update, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

[image: When I make a new contact with that first and last name, the immediate email is sent, so I know it's activating the trigger. The email alerts are set to trigger 1 Hour after "Contact: Contact Created Date"]I've been working on testing a time based workflow, that fires off an email 1 and 3 hours after a new contact is created. Of course, this is small scale testing, as I would eventually like to transition hours into week(s).

I'm having a problem getting the time based email alerts to send out. The immediate alert sends out just fine. When I go into Monitoring > Time based work flows > and look for my workflow, it shows the workflows just sitting there in the queue. I read into how to create a Debug log but the log never created because the trigger never did anything to generate any kind of errors. My workflows from last week's test, are still sitting in the queue when they should have fired off emails a few days ago.

I set the rule to check when contact is created as well as edited to subsequently meet the criteria. For now, my workflow logic is simple. I just checks for any contacts created in my test account. Nothing too complicated yet.

I also tried creating a brand new field, and used the formula to pull in the date/time the contact was created. Then I told the time based trigger to use that value, and fire an email off 1 hour after.

Still nothing. I've looked this up a lot online as well, but can't seem to find any type of fix.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit: I am currently testing another solution, where I used "Formula = true" to trigger the rule, and then I've told the time based work flow to trigger 1 hour after the Rule Trigger Date (which will be triggered immediately upon creating a contact)

Update: Still no luck. Will keep playing around with settings. Immediate workflows always work, but any time based email alert, never fires. Currently trying to do a time based field update instead. I can tie an email to fire off when a field goes from true to false or vice versa. For some reason, can't get the scheduled field update to show up on the time based monitor.

Update: Created another Workflow rule. The trigger is simple. When a xyz field is set to 'True', execute a time based work flow 1 hour after trigger event, which sets the field to false. Just waited an hour to test this workflow, and still nothing. Now it seems like anything relating to time based workflows simply are not working. I may have to do some digging tonight to see if I'm doing something wrong. The trigger event is always set to true. The Time Based Work Flow monitor has a queue full of actions, whose dates and times are hours past, and yet nothing has executed. Yikes!

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the workflow configurations?

Comment: Just added. Still not sure what is going on. I've also tried other logic that I know will always = true when a contact is created. I've even tried editing the contact again to make sure the criteria is met, and the time based email alerts still won't fire. They're just sitting in the queue.

Comment: No offense, but I wonder if the WF is active at all. Please paste the WF rule screen shot.

Comment: Also, in your screen shot, anytime a Contact is created or updated to have the First Name Steve & the last name Testing123, the rule is fired, are the contacts edited at all in between when the rule is triggered and when the action happens? If so, if your contact now has a new name, your rule won't fire. Also, are you manually setting the First and Last Name that are the criteria?  If not your time-based rule will not fire

Comment: Is email enabled in your sandbox?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you aware or not but Salesforce time based Workflows rarely fire on time. You can not guarantee when the rule will fire this is because the actions are queued up and there is no certain time of execution.

I have experienced this with Time Based Workflows many a times. Once I created a Rule that was suppose to fire after 20 minutes of record creation but it got executed even after three hours.

Basically my point is we are unaware about the data queued up. Hence forth might happen that workflow triggers quite late leaving us in an illusion that something is wrong with our flow! Hope I did justice. If I am wrong any where please correct me.

Thanks